# How to limit search results with several conditions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am using search function in Graph API to look for my results. However, these are usually too general. I would like to narrow results but I can't find a way to do it - Graph API offer me only narrowing results by time. On the other hand, FQL does not offer me possibility to obtain results without having IDs of objects.

I figured that the only way is to get results by Graph API and then make FQL query for each result. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can search various objects in Facebook using GRAPH API.

You can search over all public objects in the social graph with

https://graph.facebook.com/search.

The format is:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=QUERY&type=OBJECT_TYPE

Reference
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: This is not what I am asking. I would like to narrow results that can be obtained with your code - for example if I search for Page objects with "Company Name" query, I would like to get only Pages that has more than 1 like. I would like to add another condition, just like in FQL

Comment: This is not possible directly on GRAPH as of now.Graph api supports search on public objects only and "Likes" is not an object but a Facebook connection. Facebook supports only one search parameter at a time using GRAPH.